# Spring Boot 2: {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 2 (including Spring Security) but am getting the above error for *all* paths. I tried to allow all requests but it still gives the error.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

I also tried to add this to `application.properties`

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

It still gives the same error.

Spring Boot 2.2.2

Answer (score -1):

CSRF protection is enabled by default in latest version, if you are developing end points (to be used by non-browser clients) you can disable CSFR in `WebSecurityConfig`

```
http.csrf().disable()
```

Comment: What does CSRF have to do with GET requests?

Comment: Nothing, thats why it is safe to remove it (according to Spring configuration)

Answer (score -1):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11383) reported

> management.security.enabled has been removed in spring-boot 2

For me , it worked when I added a default username and password as per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#security-properties) , to the application.properties

```
spring.security.user.name=test
spring.security.user.password=test
```

and included the same in the request header.

**Update :**
Realized a bit late that my answer was not fitting the question.

To disable auto configuration , reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringBootSecurityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSecurityApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration` and `(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })` and `spring.security.user.name=test` and `spring.security.user.password=test` and restarted server and tested with `curl -i -u test:test localhost:8080/robots.txt` and it gave `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"` along with the JSON error.

Comment: From the error it appears you are using OAuth2 . Please refer this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2) for auto-configuration .

Comment: I am. I have the authorization server working in Spring 1.5 with JDBC token store, and am trying to get basic simple non-secured requests working first before I focus on (newly deprecated) OAuth2 authorization server.